# Can't install any NuGets in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to install NuGets for multiple projects, and the most convenient way is through the console. I've tried installing the packages through both the console and the "Manage NuGet Packages" interface, but both give me the same error:

```
PM> Install-Package log4net
Install-Package : Could not load file or assembly 'TTVSAddinDotNet.resources.module' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  log4net
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],      FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I'm not exactly sure what is going wrong. This seems to be a problem on just one computer. I've tried this on another computer with almost the same set up and it has worked just fine. I can't find any solutions online to this problem. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try updating NuGet or re-installing? Also, you may consider moving to Visual Studio 2015....

Comment: Sounds like you have a broken plugin/add-on that's interfering with the Nuget add-on. Can you try disabling other add-ons, restart VS, and try again?

Comment: I agree with @birryree, if "TTVSAddinDotNet" is some add in you've installed try disabling that and try again.  Also perhaps try using "Right-click solution > Manage NuGet Projects" instead of console...worth a shot.

Comment: try this Install-Package log4net -project ***YOUR PROJECT NAME***

Comment: @mason It's at work so unfortunately I can't update until I have the green light to do so. And yeah, I've updated. Haven't tried re-installing yet though.

Comment: @birryree I thought TTVSAddinDotNet was something that already came with my VS. After reading your comment I kind of got an idea of what add in (which came with a program I had to install) might be causing the problem. Disabled and it works perfectly fine now! Kind of really frustrated that I didn't figure that out earlier. But thank's a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by @birryree, this was a problem with a broken add-on. Disable the said addon (apparantly TTVSAddinDotNet comes packaged with Test Track), and restart VS.